# Match two files to get out of range of numbers and within range

Tags: unix, awk, numbers, match

File of range, for example (numbers between 1 - 4 and 6 - 9):

> BlackList_B_Number.dat

```
1     4
6     9
```

and this is the input file. for example:

> OCS_VOICECALLS_1111_11_111111

```
111111111    1    201605240042070000000236OCS4252 3.6344   
111111111    2    201605240114430000000123OCS1154 03.0537  
111111111    3    201605240246070000000009OCS0707 018.6965 
111111111    4    201605240530500000000213OCS0130 01.8881  
111111111    5    201605240601120000000015OCS0156 015.8059 
111111111    6    201605240649100000000052OCS0269 02.3725
```

Im interested to filter the $2 from input file related to Blacklist input file. I´d like to get these both outputs:

Output1 (input records out of filter):

```
111111111    5    201605240601120000000015OCS0156 015.8059
```

Output2 (input records within filter):

```
111111111    1    201605240042070000000236OCS4252 3.6344   
111111111    2    201605240114430000000123OCS1154 03.0537  
111111111    3    201605240246070000000009OCS0707 018.6965 
111111111    4    201605240530500000000213OCS0130 01.8881  
111111111    6    201605240649100000000052OCS0269 02.3725
```

I was triying many options, but i only get one of these options, not both outputs, only of them:

```
awk '
    FNR==NR{low[NR]=$1+0;hi[NR]=$2+0;next}
   {for(i in low)if($2>=low[i]&&$2<=hi[i]){print $0}}
' BlackList_B_Number.dat OCS_VOICECALLS_1111_11_111111

111111111    1    201605240042070000000236OCS4252 3.6344     1.5570     2.0773     0     000000    0     0JAVIE
111111111    2    201605240114430000000123OCS1154 03.0537    1.8992     1.1545     0     000000    0     0PPIB7
111111111    3    201605240246070000000009OCS0707 018.6965   18.4730    0.2235     0     000000    0     0PPXS8
111111111    4    201605240530500000000213OCS0130 01.8881    0.0000     1.8881     0     000000    0     0PPIB5
111111111    6    201605240649100000000052OCS0269 02.3725    1.7978     0.5746     0     000000    0     0PPIB7
```

How can i get the other one at the same time??:

```
111111111    5    201605240601120000000015OCS0156 015.8059
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You have to indent text that is supposed to be printed verbatim. All the whitespace is squeezed otherwise and linebreaks disappear.

Comment: Another question... How would you adapat or switch previous scripts to "program.awk" in order to execute as awk -f program.awk?

thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would write this:

```
filter="in"
awk -v filter="$filter" '
    NR == FNR {
        for (i=$1; i<=$2; i++) wanted[i]
        next
    }
    (filter == "in" && $2 in wanted) || (filter != "in" && !($2 in wanted))
' BlackList_B_Number.dat OCS_VOICECALLS_1111_11_111111
```

You can use the shell variable `$filter` to control.

I don't understand your last question: if you want both in and out of the filter, use

```
cat OCS_VOICECALLS_1111_11_111111
```

Comment: Another question... How would you adapat or switch previous scripts to "program.awk" in order to execute as awk -f program.awk?

thanks a lot in advance

Comment: everything in single quotes goes into the awk file.

Answer (score 0):

I think i got it just now!!!!!:

filter="in" awk -v filter="$filter" 'NR==FNR {for (i=$1; i<=$2; i++) wanted[i] ;next}($2 in wanted){print > "FILE1"}!($2 in wanted){print > "FILE2"}' BlackList_B_Number.dat OCS_VOICECALLS_1111_11_111111

cat FILE1
111111111    1    201605240042070000000236OCS4252 3.6344
111111111    2    201605240114430000000123OCS1154 03.0537 
111111111    3    201605240246070000000009OCS0707 018.6965
111111111    6    201605240530500000000213OCS0130 01.8881 
111111111    4    201605240601120000000015OCS0156 015.8059

cat FILE2
111111111    5    201605240649100000000052OCS0269 02.3725